# Restart Merge Replication After Failure

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, replication, merge-replication

I would be surprised if this has not been answered before but I cannot seem to find the answer I am looking for.

I am testing out the basic functionality of merge replication.  Changes flow between the subscriber and publisher.  One scenario I tested is the subscriber going offline before a change at the publisher is made.  In this scenario, I can see the error in Replication Monitor.  After the subscriber comes back online, how do I automatically fire the merge replication process (if this is possible)?  I have it set up to run continuous so I expected it to retry but it appears that this is not the case.

Thanks for any guidance on this issue.

Comment: I would be surprised if this hasn't been asked before - on [dba](http://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options here.

1) For the Merge Agent job, **Run agent** job step, click Edit and navigate to the **Advanced** page.  Set the **On failure action** to **Go to the next step** and create another job step 2 which runs the Merge Agent in the exact same fashion as Step 1.  Then on the **Advanced** page of Step 2, set **On failure action** to Go to step: [1] Run agent.  This will essentially put the job in a retry loop on failure.

2)  Instead of running the Merge Agent continuously, run it on a 1 minute schedule.  This is essentially the same as running the Merge Agent continuously since the continuous polling interval is a 1 minute schedule by default.  This way, the Merge Agent will run every 1 minute, even if it fails.  I prefer this approach personally.

Comment: I have tried the second option (which, from the knowledge I have gained thus far, appeared to be easier).  The only question I have relates to changing the schedule of the merge agent.  I could not find where to make the setting.  Knowing that I could specify when creating the subscription, I recreated it.  Anyhow, thank you so much for guiding me.

Comment: You're welcome.  To change an existing Merge Agent job from continuous to on a schedule, go to the Run Agent job step, click Edit, and remove the -Continuous parameter from the Command section.  Then in the Job Properties, navigate to the Schedules page and define a schedule.